# Swing - invisible column throwing exception when accessing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

**Background**
I have a JTable called table, and I have a column that is not part of the DefaultTableModel so its invisible:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Title", "Artist",
"Album", "Time"}, 0)
```

I add the respective rows like this:

```
int upTo = songList.size();
    int idx = 0;
    while (idx < upTo) {
        SongObject curSong = songList.get(idx);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
curSong.toString(), 
curSong.getArtist(), 
"-", 
curSong.getDuration(), 
curSong});
        idx++;
    }
```

Where curSong is the the current song object that it is adding, the SongObject contains all data about the song. The toString() returns the title of the song.

**Problem:**
The problem is that when I try to access the column like this:

```
SongObject songToPlay = (SongObject) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 4);
```

It throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4` exception.
Can anyone explain why and propose a solution?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Aqua I overrode the following:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Title", "Artist", "Album", "Time"}, 0) {

        @Override
        public void addRow(Object[] rowData) {
            Vector blah = DefaultTableModel.convertToVector(rowData);
            insertRow(super.getRowCount(), blah);
        }

        @Override
        public void insertRow(int row, Vector data) {
            super.dataVector.insertElementAt(data, row);
            super.fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }
    });
```

Then I accessed the item in the fifth column (which is not part of the model!) like this:

```
SongObject songToPlay = (SongObject) table.getModel().getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(
                                table.getSelectedRow()), 4); //get the value at the VIEW location NOT THE MODEL collection
```

Sorry for the messy code but it worked. Home I could help someone with a similar problem. The solution just misses the `justifyRows()` method found in `DefaultTableModel`

Answer (score 1):

`DefaultTableModel.addRow()` somewhere down the chain executes private `justifyRows()` method, which trims the unused columns from the row to the size equal to `getColumnCount()`. So the fifth column is never added to the model. As a result, you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you're attempting to access this column.

If you need access to the actual `SongObject` then you can have a custom model that would return `SongObject` for a given row index. Make an extension of `AbstractTableModel`. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial for examples.

As an alternative, you can still use `SongObject` in a visible column. Just use a custom renderder that would renderer `SongObject` as a string for example. See [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for details. You can reuse `DefaultTableModel` in this case.

Comment: Ohh myy it was as simple as just overriding a few methods. Thanks!!